# How to avoiding "options" props from being initialised inline?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Since the reference of `options` changes when `ParentComp` re-renders, what are some good methods to prevent `SubComp` rerendering when its props haven't changed? Example situation:

```
const ParentComp = ({ uri, someOtherProp }) => {
  [...some other state hooks here]
  return <SubComp options={{ uri }} someOtherProp={someOtherProp}/>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this to prevent the parent from passing a new reference for the options prop every time it renders. Now you are doing `options={{ uri }}` but `{ uri }!=={ uri }`. You are creating a new object for options even if uri didn't change.

You could use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) for this

```
const ParentComp = ({ uri, someOtherProp }) => {
  const options = React.useMemo(() => ({ uri }), [uri]);
  return (
    <SubComp
      options={options}
      someOtherProp={someOtherProp}
    />
  );
};
```

If you have lots of props and just want SubComponent to re render when something changes you can do the following:

```
const ParentComp = ({ uri, someOtherProp }) => {
  const memoProps = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      options: { uri },
      someOtherProp,
    }),
    [someOtherProp, uri]
  );
  return <SubComp {...memoProps} />;
};
```

This is assuming that SubComp is a either a class that inherits from PureComponent, component wrapped with React Redux connect or a functional component wrapped with React.memo (no need for the compare function). Normal functional components will re render even if props have same reference as previous render.

Comment: That looks pretty neat! I've heard that useMemo should only be used for complicated calculations though. Would using it in such cases be recommended? I'm guessing without benchmarking it's hard to answer this.

Comment: @KarlisFilipsons Yes because re rendering a DOM element is expensive enough, you are preventing this re render. It is used in a slightly different way [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-memoize-calculations). Memoization is a light weight operation and is used a lot in [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect). So when you use reselect to get, convert and calculate data from state you automatically get memoization so your pure components work as expected.

Comment: @KarlisFilipsons If you create a container that need to calculate props from redux store and passes that to a dumb/presentational component you can use useMemo and don't need the dumb component to be pure, it also makes for less nesting. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/react-redux-hooks/blob/master/src/components/App/index.js#L50-L52) where CounterComp is a functional (not pure) component but won't re render when calculated props didn't change.

Answer (score 2):

[React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

> If your function component renders the same result given the same
>   props, you can wrap it in a call to `React.memo` for a performance boost
>   in some cases by **memoizing** the result. This means that React will skip
>   rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

```
const ParentComp = ({ uri, someOtherProp }) => {
  [...some other state hooks here]
  return <SubComp options={{ uri }} someOtherProp={someOtherProp}/>
}

const equalProps = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  /*
  return true if passing next props would/should
  result in the same output, false otherwise
  */
};

export default memo(ParentComp, equalProps);
```

**NOTE:**

> This method only exists as a **performance optimization**. Do not rely on
>   it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

Comment: That makes sense but let's assume that the state changes internally in `<ParentComp />`, for example, through useState. Then the component would re-render causing SubComp to re-render because `options={{ uri }}` gets reinitialised.

Comment: @KarlisFilipsons We are assuming that `SubComp` is a functional component and functional components always re render even if props have same reference as previous render. So you can make SubComp in a pure component using React.memo with the compare function, something like so: `React.memo(SubComp,(prevProps, nextProps)=>prevProps.ohter===nextProps.other && prevProps.options.uri === nextProps.options.uri)` This gets complicated quickly so maybe better to use React.useMemo in parent.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention I was assuming SubComp is a PureComponent. I'm guessing the useMemo method in the parent is the best option here. Thanks!